# Javascript: Append Element to a Class Only on Specific .html File

Tags: javascript, append

New to JS. Let's say I have an `index.html` page that has a `<div class="posts">`. I also have an `about.html` page that has a `<div class="posts">`. They have the same css stylesheet linked to them, but I want the `<div class="posts">` container to hold different content per page. The same `script.js` page is linked to both files.

If I create a new div using JS like such:

```
newDiv = document.createElement('div');
postContent = document.querySelector(".posts");
postContent.append(newDiv);
```

Is there a way to append the element ONLY to the `<div class="posts">` on the `about.html` page, but not the `index.html` page?

I could just give the div on the `about.html` page a unique class name, but then the styles from the css sheet will not apply to the new class unless I manually add some duplicate styles for the new class name. I could also create a separate `.js` file just for the `about.html` page and only link it to that page.

However, in the scenario that I am trying to use this for, I will be creating many `.html` pages (think one for April 2021, one for May 2021, and on and on), so it is not feasible to keep using unique class names and adding more duplicate styles to my stylesheet for every single page, or to create new `.js` files for every single page.

How can I target an element to only be appended to the class on a specific `.html` page?

Apologies if this question has been asked before. I searched far and wide before asking here.

Comment: Use an `if` statement that checks `window.location.href`.

Comment: An element can have multiple classes. So giving the DIV on `about.html` a class that this code looks for doesn't mean it can't have the class used by CSS.

Comment: First of all: an element can be part of multiple classes. So there's no need for duplicate styles. However, my solution would be to add a unique id to the body element: `<body id="about">`. This way you can do `postContent = document.querySelector("#about .posts");` and on the index.html page, `postContent` will be undefined.

Comment: Thank you Barmar and Chris G! These are the answers I was looking for. I was thinking much too complicated >_<. I will use the multiple classes or unique ID method. I haven't heard of the window.location.href before though, so I am going to look into that one as well just for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ID attribute of the element. something like:

```
<div id="posts_of_about" class="posts">
```

and your js can be something like this:

```
newDiv = document.createElement('div');
postContent = document.querySelector("#posts_of_about");
postContent.append(newDiv);
```

its only one of a lot of solutions.

Comment: Oh my god I swear these things are right in front of my face and I spend so much time overthinking to see them. Thank you so much! This is the answer.

Comment: Sometimes it's good to leave the problem to resolve later (when it is possible lol)...You are welcome!